# IllegalAccessError on jdk-17 in a project using repast

Tags: java, openjdk-17

currently I am working on a java project that uses the repast java library (repast.jar, colt.jar and trove.jar). The project works fine with jdk-11, but currently, I am trying to migrate to jdk-17 and I am not able to run the project because of the next exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.go.trove.classfile.AccessFlags tried to access private method 'void java.lang.reflect.Modifier.<init>()' (com.go.trove.classfile.AccessFlags is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.reflect.Modifier is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.go.trove.classfile.AccessFlags.<init>(AccessFlags.java:75)
    at com.go.trove.classfile.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:160)
    at com.go.trove.classfile.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:138)
    at uchicago.src.sim.util.ByteCodeBuilder.generateBasicAction(Unknown Source)
    at uchicago.src.sim.engine.ActionUtilities.createActionFor(Unknown Source)
    at uchicago.src.sim.engine.ScheduleBase.scheduleActionBeginning(Unknown Source)
    at uchicago.src.sim.engine.ScheduleBase.scheduleActionBeginning(Unknown Source)
```

I remember reading that in a recent version of java some changes on the reflection API occurred. Would this be a possible cause?

Any idea of how to solve it? Is that hard to solve?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I suggest to open issue on their github repo.

Comment: These packages appear to be from a very old version of Repast, possibly Repast 3, so the repast-simphony tag is not appropriate.

Comment: @J.Ozik you are right. The project I am working on uses RespastJ. I read that legacy RepastJ code may be easily updated to work with Repast Simphony. Are there any resources you recommend to start this upgrade?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#%3Cinit%3E() - deprecated for removal. Removed in Java 15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea ...

The Tea / Trove project is ancient code that hasn't been maintained by the original developers (Disney Corp!).  There is fork on Github at https://github.com/teatrove/teatrove ... but that has had no activity since 2013 either.  Not promising.

As to your problem.  Well it seems that the original designers decided to make the `org.teatrove.trove.classfile.Modifiers` a subclass of `java.lang.reflect.Modifier`.

The problem is that `Modifier` used to have a *default* `public` constructor ... but in Java 14 they deprecated this constructor ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#%3Cinit%3E())).  In Java 17 there is now a `private` no-args constructor.  That means that when Trove attempts to create a `Modifiers` instance on Java 17, it fails with a binary compatibility error.

One way to solve this would be to modify Trove so that `Modifiers` is no longer a subclass of `Modifier`.  I don't know how feasible that would be.  The feasibility will depend on whether the codebase makes use of the fact that `Modifiers` is a subtype of `Modifier`.  That would be for you to investigate ...

If you take this approach, be a good citizen and submit your changes as a pull request against the "TeaTrove" codebase on Github.

Another approach would be to look for a replacement for the Trove dependency in your application.  Again, without knowing how / why you are using Trove, it is difficult to suggest an alternative.

Your application's dependency may be due to your using an old version of Repast.  I can't find any information on old Repast versions ... but this suggests another approach would be to upgrade to a newer Repast version that (hopefully<sup>1</sup>) avoids the Trove dependency.

Finally, given that the Repast developers still recommend Java 11 for the *most recent* versions of Repast, you could just stick with that.

---

<sup>1 - The Repast codebase doesn't use a modern build tool like Maven or Gradle that take a declarative approach to dependencies<sup>2</sup>.  Instead they have snarfed copies of the dependency JARs and put them into their source repo.  This makes dependency analysis difficult.

2 - See https://github.com/Repast/repast.simphony/issues/4</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much. You are right and thanks so much for the detailed answer. After jdk-13, a private constructor was added to java.lang.reflect.Modifier, so my project does not work in jdk-15,16,17. Since my project works with the legacy RepastJ, I think I will try and venture to upgrade to Repast Simphony (the currently maintained version of repast).